# Recieving an Invalid casting error mvc app -- fails on unrelated line

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I have an MVC application that uses Code-First migrations. I'm receiving the following cast error : 'The specified cast from a materialized

> 'System.Int32' type to the 'System.Guid' type is not valid.'

The app fails immediately somewhere in here:

```
if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            ViewBag.ProfilePicture = "../Assets/cow.jpg";
            Session["backColor"] = "#B40404";
            if (db.Information.Count() != 0)
            {
```

So, given where the IDE says it's failing, the error it's sending, Anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance!

here's the stack trace:

> [InvalidOperationException: The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Int32' type to the 'System.Guid' type is not valid.]
>      System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetValue(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal) +235
>      lambda_method(Closure , Shaper ) +258
>      System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper) +182
>      System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext() +78
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext() +112
>      System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +275
>      System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
>      WisconsinTrackClubWebsite.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in C:\Users\RunFranks525\Documents\Workspace\witrackclub\WisconsinTrackClubWebsite\Controllers\HomeController.cs:29
>      lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +62
>      System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
>      System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +157
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d() +50
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f() +225
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c() +26
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
>      System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9765121
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Comment: I do not think that line is causing the issue. Check the lines being executed before that. Specifically any lines dealing with a Guid/Int type(s)

Comment: yeah the line before is probably the case:             if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated).

Comment: Any ideas to the fix, then?

Comment: You need to show the relevant part of code. Without that it is hard for me to guess which part is failing !

Comment: can you post the stack trace ?

Comment: @AmitKumar posted!